# SaltStack Reactor fails with exception

Tags: configuration-management, salt

I have the next conf files for salt reactor:

1. reactor.conf

> - 'salt/netapi/hook/cd':
>
>   - /srv/reactor/dev.sls

2. dev.sls

> ```
> # vim: sts=2 ts=2 sw=2 et ai
>
> {% set payload = data.get('post') %}
>
> {%      set master = [grains.fqdn] %}
>
> core|api|{{ master }}|jenkins-cd:
>   runner.state.orchestrate:
>     - tgt: {{ master }}
>     - mods: myreactor.deploy
>     - pillar:
>         temp_var_transmit: {{ payload }}
> ```

3. deploy.sls

> ```
> {%      set payload = salt.pillar.get('temp_var_transmit') %}
> {%      set master = [grains.fqdn] %}
> my_state:
>   salt.function:
>     - name: cmd.run
>     - tgt: {{ master }}
>     - arg:
>       - "salt-run state.orch my-reactor.cd_state pillar='{\"temp_var_transmit\":{\"host\":\"{{payload['host']}}\",\"artifact_id\":\"{{payload['artifact_id']}}\",\"artifact_version\":\"{{payload['artifact_version']}}\"}}'"
> {% endfor %}
> ```
>
> 4. cd_state.sls
>
> ```
> {% set data = salt.pillar.get('temp_var_transmit') %}
> my_deploy:
>   salt.state:
>     - tgt: {{ member }}
>     - expr_form: compound
>     - sls: '{{ data.artifact_id }}_{{ data.artifact_version }}'
>     - queue: true
>     - test: {{ dry_run_mode }}
> ```

When I send API request and run salt-runner.events, I get the next error:

```
jid": "20180119065728472630", 
    "return": "Exception occurred in runner state.orchestrate: Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/salt/client/mixins.py\", line 395, in _low\n    data['return'] = self.functions[fun](*args, **kwargs)\nTypeError: orchestrate() argument after ** must be a mapping, not list\n", 
    "success": false, 
    "user": "Reactor"
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: **TypeError: orchestrate() argument after ** must be a mapping, not list\n"**  => sounds like you have a problem in your payload (or jsut a hyphen missing before your `temp_var_transmit`

Comment: What version of saltstack are you running?

Comment: @JamesShewey, 2016.11.1 (Carbon)

Comment: You might try upgrading to nitrogen to see if there was a known issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, can not upgrade in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find the root of issue. The problem was in the configuration of salt master. After every change of reactor config, I must run `salt-call state.highstate` command on master to sync reactor source code changes with it. I missed this step and thus my reactor config differed from my original source code in IDE. So once I ran mentioned command, everything became in sync. Thanks everybody for help!

P.S. regarding mentioned error, it occurred because I used kwarg in dev.sls for pillar and represented pillar as list:

```
>     kwarg:
>      - pillar:
>          temp_var_transmit: {{ payload }}
```

Kwarg can not contain a list in this case. It may contain key:value format only. So the correct way is either use without kwarg as I did or remove hyphen near pillar.

Comment: You might be relieved to know that things are changing in Nitrogen (if you every find you *can* upgrade) and you can [change the kwargs behavior](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/releases/2017.7.0.html#state-module-changes) beginning in this version. I would expect that might become the default behavior in oxygen or flurorine and the old syntax deprecated at some point.